# O(n) - the next permutation lexicographically

Tags: algorithm

i'm just wondering what is efficiency (O(n)) of [this algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation):

1. Find the largest index k such that a[k] < a[k + 1]. If no such index exists, the permutation is the last permutation.
2. Find the largest index l such that a[k] < a[l]. Since k + 1 is such an index, l is well defined and satisfies k < l.
3. Swap a[k] with a[l].
4. Reverse the sequence from a[k + 1] up to and including the final element a[n].

As I understand the worst case O(n) = n (when k is the first element of previous permutation), best case O(n) = 1 (when k is last element of previous permutation).

Can I say that O(n) = n/2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All steps in the algorithm takes `O(n)` asymptotically.

Your averaging is incorrect. Just because best case is O(1) and worst case is O(n), you can't say the algorithm takes O(n)=n/2. Big O notation is simply for the upper bound of the algorithm.

So the algorithm is still `O(n)` irrespective of the best case scenario.

Answer (score 2):

`O(n) = n/2` makes no sense.  Let `f(n) = n` be the running time of your algorithm.  Then the right way to say it is that `f(n)` is in `O(n)`.  `O(n)` is a set of functions that are at most asymptotically linear in `n`.

Your optimization makes the expected running time `g(n) = n/2`.  `g(n)` is also in `O(n)`.  In fact `O(n) = O(n/2)` so your saving of half of the time does not change the asymptotic complexity.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as O(n) = n/2.

When you do O(n) calculations you're just trying to find the functional dependency, you don't care about coefficients. So there's no O(n)= n/2 just like there's no O(n) = 5n

Answer (score 0):

Asymptotically, O(n) is the same as O(n/2).  In any case, the algorithm is performed for each of the n! permutations, so the order is much greater than your estimate (on the order of n!).

Comment: Why 'n!' ?  I have only one loop for permutation.  He is implementation https://github.com/demas/programming-challenges/blob/master/codeforces/100086/c_v2.rb